# Rewriting URL using HTACCESS for category name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the URL using htaccess... for converting below URL

- http://www.example.com/category.php?id=xyz

TO

- http://www.example.com/xyz

I don't want to write category in url, I am using below code but no use

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ category.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*) category.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a RewriteCond to manipulate query strings.

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /category\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [NE,L,R]
```